# Couldn't Fetch Mysqli

Tags: php

I have a problem fixing this code it says that

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   D:\Websites\movie-site\watch.php on line 56.php Warning:
>   mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
>   given in D:\Websites\movie-site\watch.php on line 59

Comment: Do you have a running mysqli connection? Can you show some code please?

Comment: If code could be provided, that would be awesome.

Comment: If you wish to find a solution here, you will need to be more descriptive by sharing the code that is failing, error statements (like those you have already provided), and showing that you have made a reasonable effort at trying to resolve the issue by showing attempted solutions.

Comment: **Google your warning messages** if you're not going to show us code. I failed mindreading classes in my last semester, so I can't help ya. [**And read the manual.**](http://php.net/mysqli) --- Voted to close.

Comment: I find PHP to be rather adept at providing useful error messages that are easy to Google...Java on the otherhand....

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue when i close the mysqli connection and after closing the mysqli i am performing some more queries that time i got this error. so please check that your connection to your mysqli server is working.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of the error the query you provided in `mysqli_query()` may have a syntax error in it which would explain why `mysqli_query()` wont work.

`mysqli_fetch_array()` will not work unless you have a returned result from `mysqli_query()`, good programming practice is before using `mysqli_fetch_array()` to check what has been returned by `mysqli_query()`, since it's saying that it's getting NULL in the argument an example check would be

```
if(empty(mysqli_query($conn,$query)))
{
     echo "can not execute query"; // can use anything as a friendly error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the errors you are getting, I can say that you're not passing any parameters to the `mysqli_fetch_array()` function, while it expects one argument.

You should run the `mysqli_query()` function with your SQL query as an argument and the returned result is stored to a result variable.

For example:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Peson");
```

Then you should use the `$result` variable with `msqli_fetch_query()` to fetch the result to a row array.

For example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Two mistakes in your answer. One) `mysql_` OP is using `mysqli_` and Two) that's `f`etch and not `g`etch ;-)

Comment: Oh, and if you get any downvote(s), it WON'T have come from me, it's not my style. Many do not like making reference to W3Schools.

Comment: Tanks deleted it. I didn't know that people are heating it that much